# Display subcategories selectbox on each category page

Tags: categories, templates

I want to display a select box to switch to SUBCATEGORIES of the current CATEGORY when i'm on a category page.

I've the following category structure

```
Category 1
    Subcategory 1
    Subcategory 2
    Subcategory 3
Category 2
    Subcategory 1
    Subcategory 2
```

I've created a custom template using the category slug but i need to create a selectbox at the top of the template that loads the subcategory of the current category.
How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to the categories from the post type `post` (the blog) then this would do the trick:

For a drop-down: [wp_dropdown_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories)

For a list: [wp_list_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

> `child_of`
>   Only display categories that are children of the category
>   identified by this parameter. There is no default for this parameter.

```
<?php 
  // Put the parent category ID in place of 9999
  // for a drop-down, does not need <select></select> wrapper
  wp_dropdown_categories('child_of=9999');
  // for a list, does need <ul></ul> wrapper
  wp_list_categories('child_of=9999');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on deflime's answer, but if you want a `<select>` you'll want to use the [`wp_dropdown_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_categories) function